# increment and save incrementation in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a simple scenario but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I want to save a incremented value as a int to [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) every time a user tap on a item, let me show what I have:

```
int counter = 0;

mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        counter++;
        SharedPreferences shareOpenClose = getSharedPreferences("Counter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editorOpenClose = shareOpenClose.edit();
        editorOpenClose.putInt("count", counter);
        editorOpenClose.apply();

        SharedPreferences getCount = getSharedPreferences("Counter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int getCountAmmount = getCount.getInt("count", 0);

        if (getCountAmmount>3){
        Toast.makeText(c, "success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

So, when I close the activity and open it again the counter will be reset to zero and the first save to [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) back to 0. If I keep the activity open and test this it work and I get the toast as expected.

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you never set the counter back when the activity loads. try this:

```
int counter = 0;


onCreate(...){
    SharedPreferences countPref = getSharedPreferences("Counter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    counter = countPref.getInt("count", 0);
}

mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        counter++;
        SharedPreferences countPref = getSharedPreferences("Counter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editorOpenClose = countPref.edit();
        editorOpenClose.putInt("count", counter);
        editorOpenClose.apply();


        if (counter>3){
        Toast.makeText(c, "success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear, but I want it to keep incrementing even if activity was destroyed, I don't want it to start back at 0 when the activity is created again.

Comment: @ClassA yes thats why i have put that code inside onCreate. that method is called when the activity is loaded and pulls the counter so it will resume even if the activity is destroyed

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes in your code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences shareOpenClose = getSharedPreferences("Counter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editorOpenClose = shareOpenClose.edit();
    final int[] counter = {0};
    mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            counter[0]++;

            editorOpenClose.putInt("count", counter[0]);
            editorOpenClose.apply();

            SharedPreferences getCount = getSharedPreferences("Counter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            int getCountAmmount = getCount.getInt("count", 0);

            if (getCountAmmount>3){
                Toast.makeText(c, "success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

I hope this will help you, Happy Coding